# summing by keywords and by groups in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following problem:

a dataframe with keywords and groups:

[image]

my task is to look for these keywords in another dataframe in the given description and calculate the occurrences in those descriptions - by adding columns. <- I've done that part, using the code:

```
keywords = df["keyword"].to_list()
for key in keywords:
    new_df[key] = new_df["description"].str.lower().str.count(key)
```

and the result df is:

[image]

I would like to sum them by the group given in keywords dataframe.
So all the columns within one group : gas/gases/gasoline change into column **gas** and sum the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need aggregate values by another column `group` is possible create dictionary of DataFrames with tuples in keys for groups names, join by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), aggreagte and add to existing `DataFrame`:

```
d = {(key, g): df["description"].str.lower().str.count(key) 
     for key, g in zip(df["keyword"], df['group'])}
  
df = df.join(pd.concat(d, axis=1).groupby(level=1, axis=1).sum())
```